# Packet corruption and UDP

Tags: java, networking, udp, packet

I have to simulate a client server UDP relationship by uploading files from the client to the server.  It also uses a stop and wait protocol.  My question is do I need to have code in my server class to handle corrupt packets?  I read somewhere online that a **

> UDP packet with a checksum error will be rejected by the stack. In
>   other words, it's not possible for a UDP packet with a checksum error
>   to be "received at the other end correctly", because the packet will
>   not be received at all.

**

Is that true?  Would by server simply not receive the packet resulting in my client having a packet timeout?

Comment: It'd be helpful to specify this "somewhere", so we can check that out. There's lots of "somewheres" on the net, and unfortunately "somewhere" is usually full of crap.

Comment: I just saw it posted as a comment on a forum, so its validity is very questionable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDP is a lossy protocol, it does not guarantee delivery of data. I imagine your simulation of a client server UDP relationship is a "best effort" (emulating the protocol itself) and so no, you would not need this extra code.

Answer (score 1):

I have read in many text books that some stack implimentations will provide a packet w/ an error indicating the checksum has failed while others discard the packet.  In practice all of the systems I have ever used discard the packet if the checksum fails.

If the packet is indeed dropped then the timeout + resend will suffice.